# what does $* mean in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, special-characters

What does `$*` exactly mean in a shell script?

For example consider the following code snippet

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java/com/test/Testclass $*
```

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST

Comment: All of the positional parameters from the command line calling the script:  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Comment: The docs based on POSIX are particularly useful here as they apply to more than just bash: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means all the arguments passed to the script or function, split by word.

It is usually wrong and should be replaced by `"$@"`, which separates the arguments properly.

Comment: Well, @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ (Dmitri?) already explained how $* is initially constructed as a single string.  The important thing here is that it is subsequently subjected to the shell's normal word splitting, *unless* it is quoted.  "$*" will make sure that the argument is still processed as one single, long string.  "$@" forces the argument list to be processed as an array of quoted strings.  Each has its use, and it is important to know the difference.

Answer (score 9):

It's easy to find answer by yourself: `man bash` → `/\$\*`:

> **Special Parameters**
>
> The  shell  treats  several  parameters  specially.   These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> - Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the **`IFS`** special variable.  That is, `"$*"` is equivalent to  `"$1c$2c..."`,  where  `c` is the first character of the value of the **`IFS`** variable.  If **`IFS`** is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces.  If **`IFS`** is null,  the  parameters are joined without intervening separators.

Answer (score 8):

`$*` expands to all parameters that were passed to that shell script.

`$0` = shell script's name

`$1` = first argument

`$2` = second argument
...etc

`$#` = number of arguments passed to shellscript